# gravity bottom not working with textview inside relative layout

Tags: android

My RelativeLayout has a 25sp image and 25sp text on left side and then 12sp text on right side:

```
            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/omgIcon"
                        android:layout_width="25sp"
                        android:layout_height="25sp"
                        android:src="@drawable/omg_face_emoji"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="OMG"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/omgIcon"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/HeaderFont" />

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="See All"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/LinkFont" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="HeaderFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">arial</item>
</style>

<style name="LinkFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">arial</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately, the right floating text does not align to bottom of relative layout:

[image]

The baseline of right text should be same as left text. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it does not align to the bottom of the relative layout. Why? Because the `android:gravity="bottom"` means that gravity/align inside itself and it means the text `See All` will be at the bottom of your `TextView`. You have to use the `layout_gravity` instead (but it works on `LinearLayout` only).

If you want to align bottom, just add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your `TextView`. However, if you want to align bottom of `OMG` text, you should add `android:layout_alignBottom="OMG_ID"` instead